# Create content programmatically

Tags: 8, entities

In Drupal 8, how can I create content programmatically ? 
From the "Drupal 8" administration, I created a new type "House" (contain a description, an image, a reference field to users ...). How can I create a entity type "House" from a custom module ?

In my custom module, I have a form file (contain a class who extends FormBase). In the submit callback, I want create a new "house" and set values and save the new Entity.

I don't find examples on the web, in core...

Comment: Your second question "How can I create a entity type 'House'?" is a little confusing. I think the question is "How can I create a node of the node type "House" from a custom module?" The ambiguity stems from the use of "entity type" which has a very specific meaning in Drupal and the question could be "How can I create a custom entity type called 'House' from a custom module?" or "How can I create a custom entity which uses the bundle 'House'"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following code creates a node in Drupal 8.

```php
$data = [
  'type' => 'article', 
  'title' => 'My new title', 
  'uid' => 1
];
$node = Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->create($data);
$node->save();
```

For testing code snippets like this, [`drush core-cli`](http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-7x/core/core-cli) works great.

Comment: Before the save, with the entityManager, is it possible to know for each field : what type of data must be set ? (text for text field, fid for file etc...)

Comment: The only way I know at the moment is to use another deprecated method, EntityManager::getDefinitions(), but I think if you instantiate an EntityDataDefinition via the static create method you can call getPropertyDefinitions(). Both will return definitions for each property such as title or a field. 

There is also the getFieldStorageDefinitions() which returns the same thing, but from storage entity (see getStorage('node') above). However this may not be available for non-SQL drivers.

Answer (score -1):

As of Drupal 8 nodes are now treated as entities. You can simple create a node by the following code

```
$new_page_values = array();
$new_page_values['type'] = 'my_content_type';
$new_page_values['title'] = $form_state['values']['page_title'];
$new_page_values['path'] = $new_page_path;

$new_page = entity_create('node', $new_page_values);
$new_page->save();
```

Comment: entity_create() is a deprecated method that we should avoid using. Injecting the EntityManager into the Form class or using \Drupal::entityManager are the standard ways of managing entities.