# Content Type Custom Submit Handler

Tags: nodes

I am very new to Drupal and is still learning. Please excuse if I have done my coding wrong.

**Problem:**
I wanted to add two buttons to my Content type.

- 1st button for Save Form - save the form and not publish it.
- 2nd button to Submit Form - save the form and submit it.

My Save Form button works right and it uses the default submit handler.

My Submit Form button is calling a custom submit handler and here is the code:

```
  function submit_Form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  $node = entity_create('node',$values);
  $node->save();

  drupal_set_message('Your form has been submitted. It will be reviewed by the team.');
  $redirect_path = "/user";
  $url = url::fromUserInput($redirect_path);
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
```

}

I am getting this error:

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Missing bundle for entity type node in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doCreate() (line 83 of /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php).

Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: FYI `entity_create` is deprecrated and will be removed before Drupal 9.0.0 You should use `entityManager` as shown [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179810/create-a-content-programmatically#answer-179963)

Comment: @NoSssweat ***deprecrated*** ... lots of rrrrrrrrrrrr .... PS: would be nice if you could prrrrredicrrrrt the rrrrrrrrrrrelease date of 9.0.0 ???

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens mb, I knew it looked a lil funny, `deprecated`. It says before 9.0.0 which means could be at any time in D8 life. I rather not predict any D9 release date, look what happened with D8, lol.

Comment: @NoSssweat I think it is already no longer (?!?!) included in D7 ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I think you need the contrib [entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module in order for `entity_create` to work in D7. Which explains why there isn't any official docs for it in D7.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an entity `node` a value `type` for the content type is required. If your form doesn't provide one, you can add it to the values before creating the node:

```
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  $values[] = ['type' => 'article'];
  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create($values);
```

Comment: I tried to add the type but it is still giving me the error. I also tried NoSsweat suggestion to install entity module. But it also did not solve the error. By the way I am using D8. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @ernzkeem, this is the "Missing bundle for entity type node" from the error message, but I don't know what else is in $values.

Comment: I created a Content Type with all the fields on it in the Dashboard. I am hoping that the $values gets all the values in the fields of my Content Type once the Submit Form button is clicked. I am hoping to save all that is in my node edit form. Do you know any other way to do that?

Comment: I don't think that replacing the submit is so easy. Content moderation and  Workflows is now in core, did you try this?

Comment: I tried to enable the Content Moderation and my site /admin/modules page breaks. What can I do to revert it?

Comment: modules page is back. I used drush pm-uninstall to disable the content_moderation module.